# Is it bad to leave things on an else if?

Tags: conditional-statements, if-statement

Say you have only a limited number of possible conditions lets call them a,b,c,d and you are fairly sure any other possiblities ar impossible.

Is it better to do

```
if(a)
  do_something();
else if(b)
  do_something();
else if(c)
  do_something();
else if(d)
  do_something();
```

or

```
if(a)
  do_something();
if(b)
  do_something();
if(c)
  do_something();
else
  do_something();
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly. else if's are only checked conditionally. The second one would check each if unless there was a return call after each if.

Answer (score 1):

The standard method for doing this is to use a "switch" or "case" (depending on language) statement. For example in PHP you would write:

```
switch ($condition) {
  case 'a': do_something(); break;
  case 'b': do_something(); break;
  default: do_something();
}
```

But the exact syntax will depend on the language you are writing in. In this situation, you would include the instructions for the other possibilities in the "default" section, and it's a good idea to include something in here if it is possible for the condition to be something other than "a" or "b" (otherwise you'll end up with a bug!)

Comment: some conditions may not supported in a switch block, such as switch on a particular String in Java, or if all conditions are evaluating differently (ex: if (a==b) ... else if (b==c) else if (d==e) ...)

Comment: both code snippet do different things, you can't assume that the first one is correct and propose a switch instead.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with the first one, but with an assertion or something like that in an additional `else` block.

```
if(a)
  do_something();
else if(b)
  do_something();
else if(c)
  do_something();
else if(d)
  do_something();
else
  assert(0); // or throw ImpossibleException or whatever
```

(this suggestion applies also to `switch` blocks with the `default` label)

Even if you assume that it is impossible, in general it's still good "defense in depth" practice to have an additional check: at some time you may change your application somewhere else so that the possible choices become more (the typical case is adding an `enum` value) and forget updating this part of code; without such a check you have a bug that may go unnoticed for a long time.

Comment: You can't assume that his conditions are exclusive, so maybe both snippet will have different results. There isn't a "better" solution without more information.

Comment: @Krtek: he says "you are fairly sure any other possiblities are impossible", I started with this assumption.

Comment: Yeah, but he didn't say "a and b can't be true a the same time."

Answer (score 1):

There is no "better" way, it all depends on how control flow needs to go.

```
if(a)
  do_something();
else if(b)
  do_something();
else if(c)
  do_something();
else if(d)
  do_something();
```

This is a **branching control flow**, meaning that the `if` will be tested in first-appear order and the first one encountered evaluated to true will be picked and executed among all the conditions, all the remaining ones will be skipped.

```
if(a)
  do_something();
if(b)
  do_something();
if(c)
  do_something();
else
  do_something();
```

This is a **sequential control flow** (though your last if is a branching one), meaning that all `if` block will be tested and each one evaluated to true will be picked and executed. (Though the last one, as if `c` is false, only the else block will be executed.)

Choosing which one to use depends entirely on what needs to be executed. As for `switch` blocks, they are mostly shortcuts to the branching control flow, and *usually* behave exactly the same once compiled, however this is not necessarily true (i.e. when not using `break`, or some language support `goto` a different case, etc.), but this is out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

In the latter example you are always evaluating all the conditions, while the first one only evaluates them until if finds the `true` one. So the first piece of code would perform slightly better.

If you don't like so many nested conditions, `return`/`break` the method after finding the first one:

```
if(a)
  return do_something();
if(b)
  return do_something();
if(c)
  return do_something();
return do_something();
```

...unless you are devoted believer of the *Church of the single `return`*.

Answer (score 0):

The two codes snippet are different.

In the first one, each `else if` will be tested if and only if the precedent condition was wrong. For example, if `a` was right, the others won't be tested at all.

The second snippet test each condition whatever the precedent was.

Like said in another answer, the first snippet can be replaced with a `switch` statement depending on the conditions and the language your using. But the second snippet must be left as it is.

So my final word will be : this is not a question of "better or not" since both codes do different things. **It depends on what you want to do !**

Answer (score 0):

The second version will evaluate each if statement regardless of the outcome of previous evaluations.

In fact it will even show **wrong behavior** for what you want to achieve, because the last else is always entered if the condition is not c. And not if it is not one of a, b or c.

The first version should work as expected.